# How to activate , ShortCut Key in context menu in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, contextmenu

How to activate shortcut key for Context menu item. I try the following things, But the shortcut key was not triggered, but at the same time if we click with the mouse it works fine.

```
    menu = QMenu()
    atoz_action = QAction(QIcon('d://icon//atoz_4.png'),"Sort A to Z",self)
    atoz_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_R))
    atoz_action.triggered.connect(self.ascending_order)
    menu.addAction(atoz_action)
```

**Addition: Minimal reproducible example** As directed by musicamante, I here add a minimal reproducible example.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyCheckableComboBox(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setEditable(True)
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {border: none;padding-left: 5px;}")
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.RightClickMenu)

    def RightClickMenu(self,pos):
       
        menu = QMenu()

        atoz_action = QAction("Sort A to Z",self)
        atoz_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_R))
        atoz_action.triggered.connect(self.ascending_order)
        menu.addAction(atoz_action)

        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(QPoint(pos)))

    def ascending_order(self):
        print("1111ascending order")


class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.data = ['America', 'Russia', 'China', 'Germany', 'France', 'India']

        self.combo = MyCheckableComboBox()
        self.combo.setMinimumSize(600,40)

        btn = QPushButton('Print Values')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.getValue)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.combo)
        mainLayout.addWidget(btn)

        self.combo.addItems(self.data)

    def getValue(self):
        print(self.combo.currentText())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''QWidget {font-size: 20px;}''')
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()
    app.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The shortcut context is only active as long as the object containing it is. This means that your code will only work when the menu is shown (since it has not parent). If you're executing the above code only within a `ContextMenu` event (such as a `contextMenuEvent()` override or through a function connected to a `customContextMenuRequested` signal), the action will *never* be triggered. If you want a more comprehensive answer, then please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: @musicamante, as per direction, add a MRE

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard shortcut is only active as long as it's created within its context.

There are many issues about this aspect within your code, but, most importantly:

- `RightClickMenu` is a function that is called only whenever the `customContextMenuRequested` signal is emitted: before that, the action doesn't exist, so there is absolutely **no way** that it could get triggered;
- the menu created within that function only exists within the scope of that function; since the menu has no parent, it will be destroyed as soon as the function will return (and its action along with it);
- creating an action with a parent is not enough to make it "active", you **must** also call [`addAction()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction): QAction ownership doesn't automatically activate the action, especially if the action is triggered by a shortcut that has a more broad context (which is the default);

Other relatively minor (but still important) issues:

- the `CustomContextMenu` policy is useful for external objects (normally, parents); if you need to handle a context menu event, you should override [`contextMenuEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent) (as already explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74900713/2001654) to your previous question);
- only classes and constants should have capitalized names, not functions;
- the creation of QObjects with parents should be done with major awareness, otherwise they will just be kept alive even when they are not needed anymore; actions of a temporary menu should use the menu as parent, or added using `QMenu.addAction()`;

```py
class MyCheckableComboBox(QComboBox):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setEditable(True)
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {border: none;padding-left: 5px;}")

        self.atozAction = QAction("Sort A to Z", self)
        self.atozAction.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.CTRL + Qt.Key_R))
        self.addAction(self.atozAction)
        self.atozAction.triggered.connect(self.ascending_order)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction(self.atozAction)
        menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

    def ascending_order(self):
        print("1111ascending order")
```

Comment: @Bala 1. I really hope that you're not using multiple accounts, as it's a highly discouraged and disliked practice (that can also lead to ban); 2. sorry, but I really don't understand what you're asking; 3. even ignoring point 1 and assuming that you're the OP, you should've clarified that requirement since the beginning: you've been using StackOverflow for enough time to know that we expect questions that are *final* to their requests; if you don't clarify what you need we can't help you, and, frankly, late adding of such details (which should've been clarified way before) is quite annoying.